# Correct choice of proof for showing that there is an integer satisfying $5^n=n^5$

Tags: proof-writing

I am wanting to start a proof for the following statement:

> Prove that there is an integer $n$ such that $5^n=n^5$.

Would proof by construction be an appropriate method to use?

Then would proof by induction be an appropriate method to use?

Comment: Let $n=5$ . . .

Comment: Just show the value $n.$ You can prove $n$ is unique using unique factorization.

Comment: Proof ["by inspection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon#Proof_techniques).

Comment: @Blue What is "by inspection"? I have only learned Construction, Contradiction, Induction so far.

Comment: Construction means you just construct a solution. By inspection means you looked at it and can see that $n = 5$ works. It was still a constructed solution, though.

Comment: @user430574:  click on the blue words in Blue’s comment for an explanation of “by inspection”

Comment: @user430574: The link goes to a Wikipedia entry describing the phrase "by inspection". Basically, it means "proof by look!-it-works" when there's an "obvious" solution. As @ Derek notes, this probably counts as a proof by construction; there just isn't much construction effort to make.

Comment: @user430574, perhaps a more worthwhile aim would be to prove that there is only one integer $n$ satisfying your equation?

Comment: Induction proofs are about properties that hold for all natural numbers or all natural numbers beginning with some specific number, this cannot be applied here.